# Incrementar correlativo con un insert

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla con esta estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba_insert` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asiento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `correlativo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `glosa` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Deseo insertar un registro que incremente los valores de id, asiento y correlativo. Tengo este código de prueba.

```
<?php
require ('includes/config.php');
$BD = new ConexionDB();    
$sql = "SET @id:= (SELECT max(id) from prueba_insert);
SET @asiento:= 8;
SET @corr:= (SELECT max(correlativo) from prueba_insert);
INSERT INTO prueba_insert (id, asiento, correlativo, glosa)
values (@id:=@id+1, @asiento:=@asiento+1, @corr:=@corr+1, 'GLOSA PARA ASIENTO')";
$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

NOTA FINAL: Sí funciona el SET dentro de la sentencia. Lo único que tenía que hacer era quitar el "as" de cada incremento. FIN.

Comment: Hola, por que no funciona con lo de ahi abajo? te da fallos?

Comment: Sale este error en el segundo execute(): "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'"

Comment: Por favor, añade ese mensaje de error a la pregunta. Tienes que tratar de dejar todda la informacion relevante en la pregunta y pensar que un comentario puede desaparecer en cualquier momento. Un saludo

Comment: Ambos inserts están muy similares, utilizan las mismas tablas y columnas. Seguro que sólo falla uno de los dos inserts y no ambos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el segundo insert estás intentando leer los campos `id` y `corr` de una tabla que no está entre las cláusulas FROM. De hecho, ni siquiera me consta que puedas asignar el valor de la variable de esta manera aunque `tabla` estuviese dentro del FROM.

Lo que puedes probar es declarar la función usando `SET` antes del insert:

```
$sql = "
    SET @id = SELECT max(id) from tabla;
    SET @corr = SELECT max(corr) from tabla;
    INSERT INTO tabla (id, libro, asiento, correlativo, dato) 
    SELECT @id:=@id+1 as id, $libro, $valorAsto, @corr:=@corr+1 as corr, dato
    FROM tabla2;
";

$sth = $BD->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: Con tu respuesta modifiqué la pregunta para incrementar valor, pero igual no funcional.

Comment: Y tienes cómo probar si funciona en phpmyadmin? A lo mejor las sentencias preparadas del driver php no permiten fijar una variable mediante `SET`.

Comment: Hice muchas pruebas y encontré el problema basándome en tu respuesta. :)